# JavaFX: Get the x and y pixel coordinates clicked on an ImageView

Tags: java, javafx

I have an ImageView inside a ScrollPane. I can get the mouse click event by adding a listener to the ScrollPane. However, I want to get the x and y coordinates of the pixel on the image that was clicked.

To make it even more complicated, the image can be zoomed in and out on, but I can probably figure that out once I have some idea of what I am doing.

Comment: Did you try getSceneX or getScreenX or getX? What about y?

Comment: These both get the x on the screen, not of the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the mouse listener to the `ImageView` instead of to the `ScrollPane`.

Here is a simple example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClickOnScrollingImage extends Application {

    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_feature/public/thumbnails/image/crop_p_color2_enhanced_release_small.png?itok=5BtHNey_" ;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(IMAGE_URL);
        scroller.setContent(imageView);

        // the following line allows detection of clicks on transparent
        // parts of the image:
        imageView.setPickOnBounds(true);

        imageView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            System.out.println("["+e.getX()+", "+e.getY()+"]");
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(scroller, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mouse listeners do not work in ImageViews. I have to add it to the ScrollPane and check if getTarget() is the ImageView.

Comment: It does indeed work with a different image. The transparent pixels in the image were stopping the event from working.

Comment: But it doesn't work if the imageview has been resized (stretching its picture, pixels look bigger or smaller). In that case, the mouse getX/getY coordinates don't match the pixel coordinate anymore.